# How to add different CSS design to every image that I display using while loop in php

Tags: php, css, while-loop

Can anyone please help me on how to apply different CSS Design to my image that is displayed using *while* loop in PHP. I want to know if I can apply  adifferent design in every image I fetch from my database.

```
<?php

 $new = $_GET['id'];                         

 $imageResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM postimage ORDER BY post_id = '$new'  LIMIT 5");

 while( $imageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($imageResult)){

     echo "
         <div class='col-md-6 main-box' id='clickme'>
             <img class='box1 image-gallery' src='../img_upload/".$imageRow['name']."'' style='object-fit:cover;'>
         </div>";

 }
?>
```

> This is the code I use in displaying my image from my database
> [This is what I get on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN9yk.jpg)

[This is how I want to display my image(I can apply css design on every image to resize and adjust their position )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu7CH.jpg)

> note: this image was stored in my database using join table so this was fetch and display using the same id (which is my post_id). I really appreciate any help from you guys thank you so much in advance

Comment: yes Im sorry AD7six sir I will do nxt time .. I am just new in this community and still learning on how to use stack overflow thank you sir

Comment: You are rendering multiple DIVS with the same ID ***id='clickme'***, IDs need to be unique. This is not a good practice and will result in invalid HTML code. Change those id's to a class.

Comment: ohh!  that Id sir is for my javascript function to call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an index to the particular class and based on that you can view that image properly  `.image-1 { ... your CSS }`

```
<?php

 $new = $_GET['id'];
             
                      

                    $imageResult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM postimage ORDER BY post_id = '$new'  LIMIT 5");
                
                       $count = 0;
                       while( $imageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($imageResult)){
                          $count++;
                          echo "

                            <div class='col-md-6 main-box image-".$coun."' id='clickme'>

                                <img class='box1 image-gallery' src='../img_upload/".$imageRow['name']."''
                                    style='object-fit:cover;'>

                            </div>";
                    }
                
                    ?>
```

Comment: I am sorry sir if I haven't approved it immediately like what I say I am just new in here but anyway thank you so much again sir for your help ;)